# How to build Angular App having(only one page (SPA) and rest normal PHP pages?

Tags: php, angular, codeigniter

Q.Actually I want to know how to create an **Angular PHP** application.
Where I want the only page to be ***Angular(Single Page Application)*** and rest should be Normal loadable ***PHP*** pages.

-Actually I have built a complete application with PHP Codeigniter, and now i have planned to create only one module of application with Angular.

So I want to know, is it possible to create Angular and PHP applications where some pages are used in SPA application and rest would be normal PHP loadable pages?

Answer (score 0):

After you finish building the angular app and invoke the `ng build` command, Just change the name of `index.html` to `index.php`, and upload the files to your server.

I suggest you put the angular page in a different subdomain or at least a different directory to make it easier for the linking.

Something like:

- app.example.com for the angular
- www.example.com for the PHP files

Comment: IDK why is that a good solution. Just use the SPA is it is, and link to the PHP pages as they are right now. no need for subdomain, or changing the index.html to index.php